# UIImageViews overlapping each other in a paging UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, xcode6

I have tried to make a ScrollView similar to the one in the Photos app in iOS but after writing the following lines of code i still seem to be having some problems

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

   @interface ViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
   @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray * ContentList;
   @property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray * pageViews;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *PageControl;

   @end

@implementation ViewController
-(NSArray *)ContentList
{
if (!_ContentList) {
    _ContentList = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo_1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo_2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo_3"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo_4"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo_5"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo_7"]];
}
return _ContentList;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  [self ContentList];
  NSUInteger numOfpages = _ContentList.count;

NSMutableArray * views = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numOfpages; i++) {
    [views addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

self.pageViews = views;

self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.contentSize =
CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame) * numOfpages, CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame));
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;


_PageControl.numberOfPages = numOfpages;
_PageControl.currentPage = 0;

NSLog(@"the number of objects in the array is %lu",_ContentList.count);
NSLog(@"the number of objects in the mutable array is %lu",_pageViews.count);

[self LoadScrollViewWithPage:0];
[self LoadScrollViewWithPage:1];

    }

  -(void)LoadScrollViewWithPage:(NSInteger)page
 {
if (page >= self.ContentList.count ||page < 0)
    return;

// replace the placeholder if necessary
UIView * view = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)view == [NSNull null])
{
    UIImageView * newView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[_ContentList objectAtIndex:page]];

    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(frame) * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    newView.frame = frame;
    newView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    newView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:newView];

    [_pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newView];


}

}

  -(void)PurgePage:(NSInteger)page
{
if (page < 0 || page > _ContentList.count) {
    return;

}

UIView * view = [_pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)view != [NSNull null]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [_pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];
}

}

 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
// switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
CGFloat pageWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame);
NSUInteger Currentpage = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
self.PageControl.currentPage = Currentpage;


NSInteger PagebeforeCurrentPage = Currentpage - 1;
NSInteger PageAfterCurrentPage = Currentpage + 1;
// load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)


// a possible optimization would be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible

self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < PagebeforeCurrentPage; i++) {
    [self PurgePage: i];
}

[self LoadScrollViewWithPage:PagebeforeCurrentPage];
[self LoadScrollViewWithPage:Currentpage];
[self LoadScrollViewWithPage:PageAfterCurrentPage];

for (NSInteger p = PageAfterCurrentPage; p < _pageViews.count; p++)
{
    [self PurgePage:p];
}
  }
```

1. The first 2 views in the scrollviews are larger than they are supposed to be even though i set their content mode to UIViewContentModeAspectFit.
2. You cannot see the next page you are scrolling to until you are fully on that page i.e the view only appears when you are on that page
3. The 3rd view is overlapping, it is on top on the 2nd view
4. The 1st and the 2nd view shrink back to their normal sizes after you've scrolled past the 3rd view
5. You can still scroll after the last view and if you scroll after that you get an NSRangeException saying "-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]"

please help

Comment: You should use a `UICollectionView` to do this. What you have here is basically writing one yourself from scratch but with lots of bugs. There is lots of sample code out there using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to accomplish similar things. Here is one example: http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/

Comment: @Dima thank you i have seen the example. it was very helpful ...... but what if i want to pan the images in the collection view ..... do you have any idea how i can go about this

Comment: What do you mean? Dragging is built into scrollviews and therefore collectionviews. If you implement the view the panning will just work.